# Does computers on same LAN share their hosts file between each others?

Tags: networking, lan

Does computers on same LAN share their hosts file between each others? As I do not have access to the iPad host file, I was wondering if my iPad would try to resolve an address by asking other computer in the LAN network.

Comment: What makes you think it shares the host file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The devices do not share a Hosts file. However, they have several other ways of finding other computers on the network based on their name:

1. Talk to a DNS server on the LAN. Sometimes your router will do this for you, or you can set up your own DNS server.
2. Use [NetBIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS)
3. Use [WINS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Internet_Name_Service)

Comment: 4. Use Multicast DNS

Answer (score 1):

No, the file is local only, so it can be customized per host. Also, you device will not attempt IP/DNS lookups by asking other computers, unless your router was set to provide the other computers address as the DNS server for your network, and the computer runs DNS services.

at the Data link Layer, yes, the device does "ask" other computers for instructions to locations (whats the IP for this mac? ) but that is only used to navigate your local network so the device can contact the internet through your gateway.

Answer (score -1):

Add something to your PC's Host file and check your iPad to see if you can still access that site.

(You can)

Comment: This is an anecdotal comment at best, not really an answer.

Comment: sure trying is the best but it didn't seemed to work so I asked.